# How to implement abstract methods in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, abstract-class

Rather simple one this. I'm trying to generate the abstract methods in a base class in Xamarin Studio. VS lets you automatically inherit them. How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first line of the class declaration:

```
public class bar : foo
```

right-click `foo` and select "Refactor - Implement abstract members".